# Sequence of columns displayed in output by sproc

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_1 (
    p_table_owner   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_result        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
    AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_result FOR 
SELECT
    index_name,
    index_description,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys,','),',') as Index_Keys,
    include_cols,
    index_filter,
    data_compression,
    allow_page_locks,
    table_name,
    index_type    
 from 
  (
  Select t.*,  
    row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by INDEX_NAME) as rn
    from 
    (
     SELECT      
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
                      FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
                      WHERE
       -- di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
        di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        partitioned = 'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE"
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
        --di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
        dip.composite != 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT       
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
           owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_subpartitions dis
        ON dis.index_owner      = di.owner AND
           dis.index_name       = di.index_name AND
           dis.partition_name   = dip.partition_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
      --  di.table_owner = 'CON$' AND
       di.table_name = 'CON$' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
       dip.composite = 'YES' ) t      
)
```

For the following index definition:

Answer (score 1):

## Preferred Method

Your method is only valid for ancient versions of Oracle.  Instead, you should use the `LISTAGG()` aggregate.

Documentation: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Example code:

```
SELECT
  di.table_name
 ,di.index_name
 ,LISTAGG( ci.column_name,', ' ) WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY ci.column_position ) column_name_csv
FROM dba_indexes di
  JOIN dba_ind_columns ci ON
    ci.index_owner   = di.owner
  AND ci.index_name    = di.index_name
WHERE
  di.table_name   = 'CON$'
GROUP BY
  di.table_name
 ,di.index_name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Answer originally left in comments by [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)*</sub>

You probably need to provide an order by in the window function:

```
row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by INDEX_NAME)
```

There's a `COLUMN_POSITION` in `dba_ind_columns` I think.

So probably:

```
row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by COLUMN_POSITION) as rn
```

or even more simply, without any function: `COLUMN_POSITION as rn`.

You have to add the `column_position` column in the (`t`) subquery, too, in all 3 `UNION` parts. It can't find it otherwise.